# Android - Passing multiple value from BaseAdapter to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Previously, I used to pass data from Adapter to Fragment by using the `getItemId()` method. That was only one value so it wouldn't be much problem. Right now I want to take two values from the Adapter and pass it to my ListFragment.

Here is the code for `getItemId` I used currently:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    long item_id = Long.parseLong(getItem(i).getItem_id());

    return item_id;
}
```

In the ListFragment I'm using an interface to interact with the root activity. So I capture the data String from the Adapter like so:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String user_id = String.valueOf(l.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
    //String item_id = String.valueOf(l.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
    //I want to pass two values here
    mListener.onLatestSelected(user_id, item_id);
}
```

How am I going to be able to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you just use getItem() ?

Comment: Please excuse my noobishness, then how do I retrieve the String values from the `getItem()`?

Comment: l.getAdapter().getItem(position) in onListItemClick